# Links to elections from mini-sites do not show full nomination list

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, mini-site

If you go to a [mini-site](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com), the election link takes you to a [page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/election) that is missing most of the nominations.  It would probably be best if the list just took you to the full sites nomination page.

Comment: Hmm... And conveniently excludes the guy who promised to close Facebook questions... I smell a rat!

Comment: Hahahaha, how cool! When mini-sites go too far.

Comment: Oh boy, does that mean that if they manage to accumulate enough rep in the `facebook` tag, low-rep candidates can sneak in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are now correctly directed to the main site for elections. Thanks for spotting this.

I'm not sure what is with the "missing most of the nominations" - they share a database, so... anyway, best not to worry about that too much now it is fixed.